# Python Finding if Item in list in another list

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, match

I want to see if an item in the list matches with another item in a seperate list.

I then want to print the matching items.

```
columns1= ['Dog', 'cat' , 'bird', 'fish']
columns2= ['Dog', 'CAT', 'bird', 'rat']

for col in columns1:
    if col.upper() in [x.upper() for x in columns2]:
        print(col, 'Matches with', )
    else:
        print(col, 'DOES NOT Match With Anything')
```

Current output:

```
Dog Matches with
cat Matches with
bird Matches with
fish DOES NOT Match With Anything
```

Desired output:

```
Dog Matches with Dog
cat Matches with CAT
bird Matches with bird
fish DOES NOT Match With Anything
```

I've tried using `list_name.index(string_here)`, but then it ***is*** case sensitive:

```
for col in columns1:
    if col.upper() in [x.upper() for x in columns2]:
        z = columns2.index(col)
        print(col, 'Matches with', columns2[z] )
    else:
        print(col, 'DOES NOT Match With')

output:
Dog Matches with Dog
ValueError: 'cat' is not in list
```

I could make a separate list that capitalizes everything in the lists, but I feel like that is cheating and with a very large dataset will create unnecessary performance hits.

What's the better way to solve this?

Comment: can the lists be?`columns1= ['Dog', 'cat' , 'bird', 'fish']
columns2= ['CAT,'Dog', 'bird', 'rat']`

Comment: yes, they can be mismatching

Comment: How many items do you expect to exist for "very large datasets"?

Comment: @MattP, It wouldn't be uncommon for something to exceed the gigabytes level. Just want to future proof.

Comment: I meant columns/items in the list of column names. This would be relevant to performance of creating/searching a list vs creating/searching a dict or set.

Comment: @MattP, Currently, under 1,000. But if I wanted to scale this out, it could be on an entire database with what seems like uncountable columns.

Comment: @Mattr: if you work with a database, I propose that you do the search at database level: usually databases are highly optimized for these tasks. And it will usually also reduce the amount of traffic between the database and the program.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I agree. This is something that is done in our SQL database already. We are currently testing performance for all options and Python was an option that was discussed.We also work with flat files before loading the files into a database, this is where I think Python can come in handy before it's loaded to SQL

Comment: Is it possible that list items/column names are repeated?

Comment: @MattP, It is possible, but unlikely that they will be repeated.

Comment: What's wrong with a double for loop ? https://gist.github.com/ychaouche/67d4c4b167d0eb76cb6e121c95d45891

Comment: @ychaouche: this will make the algorithm *O(m n)* with *m* and *n* the dimensions of the columns. Usually we want to keep it *O(m+n)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the *performance hit* is here that you **search in a list**. This is *linear search* which is *O(n)*. If you **store the values in a dictionary**. Then the average lookup time will be *O(1)* which is way faster. Furthermore the `str.upper()` will only be called *once* per item.

So you first prepare a dictionary:

```
lookup = {k.upper():k for k in columns2}
```

Next we can use:

```
for col in columns1:
    result = lookup.get(col.upper())
    if result is not None:
        print(col, 'Matches with', result )
    else:
        print(col, 'DOES NOT Match With')
```

The `lookup.get(..)` method will lookup if `col.upper()` is in the dictionary (note that the keys in the dictionary are in uppercase as well). If it is in the dictionary `result` will be the corresponding original value of `columns2`. If not `None` will be returned. We thus only have to check for `None` to know if the lookup was successful.

This generates:

```
Dog Matches with Dog
cat Matches with CAT
bird Matches with bird
fish DOES NOT Match With
```

Comment: This is actually brilliant. I thought about dictionaries because of their performance, but couldn't think of a way to do it. Thank you!